# Cron expression for running a task immediately then keep running after every 55 minutes

Tags: cron, quartz-scheduler, spring-scheduled

I am writing a spring scheduler, and want to write a cron-expression requirement is like:

```
1) Scheduler must run when the application boots up.
2) After booting it job must keep runs after every 55 minutes.
```

Example: Application starts at 9:05 am scheduler must run when application starts at 9:05 am, After this scheduler will run at 10:00 am then 10:55 am....11:50 am...so on.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cron expressions don't mix well with fixed-interval scheduling. This is in part because Quartz Scheduler doesn't implement the full cron syntax.

If you're allowed to, you should use `SimpleScheduler` and its `withIntervalInMinutes` method. Like this:

```
yourTrigger = yourTriggerBuilder
                .withSchedule(simpleSchedule()
                        .withIntervalInMinutes(55)
                        .repeatForever())
                .startAt(new Date())
                .build();
```

This will schedule your job to run as soon as it is scheduled and then every 55 minutes.

I'm not familiar with Spring scheduling options, but I'm guessing it has a "run every X seconds" option which you could use, too.